# Best way to declare list property in model and populate it with seed method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm creating a simple movie app that will show a list of movies and will have an admin panel that can edit the movie info. I've created my models for the actors and movies table but am having trouble figuring out the best way to declare the movie genre property.

Basically my problem is twofold in that I'm not sure if Genre should be its own table that links into the movie table, or if it should be declared into a list. In simpler terms, this:

```
public class Movie
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public Rating? Rating { get; set; }
    public int Ranking { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

Or this:

```
    public class Movie
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Genre { get; set; } 
    public Rating? Rating { get; set; }
    public int Ranking { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

...and how this can be populated in the seed method when I create the movie objects.

```
var movies = new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie {Title = "Pineapple Express", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2008-08-06"), Rating = Rating.R},
            new Movie {Title = "American Hustle", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-12-13"), Rating = Rating.R},
            new Movie {Title = "40 Year Old Virgin", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2005-08-09"), Rating = Rating.R},
            new Movie {Title = "Ant Man", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2015-07-09"), Rating = Rating.PG13},
            new Movie {Title = "This Is The End", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2013-06-12"), Rating = Rating.R},
            new Movie {Title = "Anchorman: The Legend of Ron Burgundy", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2004-07-09"), Rating = Rating.R}
        };

        movies.ForEach(m => context.Movies.Add(m));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I tried going online but am having trouble finding examples of models that contain lists that would fit my example (or maybe I'm not sure how to look for it?). Any help or direction would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Genre property will be populated in the seed method when the project loads (Action, Comedy, Horror, etc). and that this list should be editable in the admin panel by a user (add genre only). I just don't know how to declare it in the Movie object once it has been populated. Not sure if this information helps, but putting it here in case it makes a difference in the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the Genres as an Enum .That will save you from creating a new table for genres  . You can declare the enum as following in a separate Genres.cs file :

```
  namespace Movies.Models
{
    public enum Genres
    {
        Horror = 0,
        Action = 1,
        Comedy = 2,
        Thriller = 3,
        //Add whatever genres here 
    }
}
```

Now you will use the enum in the seeding not in the model properties you will keep the list of strings property, so this will be your model :

```
   public class Movie
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Genre { get; set; } 
    public Rating? Rating { get; set; }
    public int Ranking { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

The seeding method will look like this :

```
var movies = new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie {Title = "Pineapple Express", ReleaseDate = DateTime.Parse("2008-08-06"), Rating = Rating.R,Genre.Add(Genres.Action.ToString())}//You can use AddRange to add more than one genre
        };

        movies.ForEach(m => context.Movies.Add(m));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

you will have to make your enum as general as possible , add all the genres to it and pick the ones you need for your film.

If you are intending to make this more fluent and generic you will have to make a table for the genres with a one to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question in your comment. If you're going to allow the user to edit / add entries to the genre it should be a table.

If you're going to have more than one genre per movie you may well need another cross reference table as well to hold the MovieId and GenreId. You can then lookup all the genre's associated with a movie.